# How do i include a footnote in a LaTeX paper?

Tags: footnotes

I'm writing my first research paper in LaTeX, and I need help on how to include a footnote, such as the Mathematics Subject classification? Or where else besides a footnote can in put the MSC? Maybe just below the abstract?

Comment: Welcome to LaTeX! [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem, or what you would like to try to do.  Also, are you sure that you mean [footnote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Note_(typography))?  If so, then the comment you're looking for is just `\footnote{content of the footnote}`.

Comment: Is this question about how to create a footnote in a LaTeX document, or are you looking for general advice on how to provide an important detail to your document (regardless of the typesetting engine that's employed)? If it's the latter, the question is probably off-topic for this site.

Comment: Some publisher's classes (the layout, the `XX` in `\documentclass{XX}`) imposes a place to put the MSC. For instance, [the class](http://www.lmcs-online.org/Information/lmcs.cls) used by [LMCS](http://www.lmcs-online.org) imposes to put the ASM classification in a `\subjclass{}` environment.

Answer (score 2):

Are you asking really about footnotes ? then the answer is

```
\footnote{the required description}
```

that's all and it should be written wherever you want to put your footnote.